# Bridging Objective-C into Swift Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm trying to put a bridging header file into my Swift project so I can use the Venmo SDK. I've placed the header file where I believe it should go and have added it to the Swift Complier - Code Generation section under build settings.

The bridging header is titled BridgingHeader.h and is directly under the project subsection (would post photo but I don't have enough reputation). It's in the same location as this link:

[image]

Under the swift compiler - code generation my path to the bridging header is BridgingHeader.h. Initially I tried to reference the file from the root directory but I still had an error saying error:

> bridging header '/Users/j9/Desktop/uSell-swift/BridgingHeader.h' does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the compiler is looking for .../BridgingHeader.h, while the actual name is LearnSwift-Bridging-Header.h.

By the way, you can avoid these annoyances by adding an ObjC class `File->New->Source->Objective C file`... It will create and configure the header for you.